# Creating own toolbar leveraging existing org.eclipse.ui.menus extension

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have custom editor for eclipse. For particular reasons this editor provide two toolbar areas which are not based on standard action bars provided by eclipse for editor. This two places are dedicated for other plugins to contribute. My intention is to leverage "org.eclipse.ui.menus" extension point with custom `menuContribution/locationURI` so other plugins can contribute using this extension and associated `toolbar:my.editor.toolbar1` and `toolbar:my.editor.toolbar2` as `locationURI`.

My problem is how to "connect" my ToolBar with particular location. I tried following approach but result are not good. I created custom `ToolbarContributionRoot` event if I should not and also created `CustomContributionFactory` which extends `ExtensionContributionFactory`. It works pretty well, but problem is with pulldown commands which submenu is not resolved correctly.

```
    toolbarManager = new ToolBarManager(SWT.FLAT);                                                        
ToolbarContributionRoot toolbarRoot = new ToolbarContributionRoot(toolbarManager);                    

IServiceLocator workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();                                                

IConfigurationElement[] allMenuElements                                                               
        = Platform.getExtensionRegistry().getConfigurationElementsFor("org.eclipse.ui.menus");        
for (IConfigurationElement menuContribution : allMenuElements) {                                      
    String locationURI = menuContribution.getAttribute("locationURI");                                

    if ("toolbar:my.editor.toolbar1".equals(locationURI)) {                                                       
        try {                                                                                         
            ExtensionContributionFactory factory = CustomContributionFactory.create(menuContribution);
            factory.createContributionItems(workbench, toolbarRoot);                                  
        } catch (CoreException e) {                                                                   
            e.printStackTrace();                                                                      
        }                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                     


toolbar = toolbarManager.createControl(root);                                                         
GridData gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, false, false, 1, 1);                   
toolbar.setLayoutData(gridData);                                                                      
toolbar.pack();
```

plugin.xml of "user" looks like this:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus" id="my.helper.id">
    <menuContribution locationURI="toolbar:my.editor.toolbar1">
        <command commandId="my.editor.special.command1" />...
```

Do you have any suggestions how to blend my custom toolbars and `"org.eclipse.ui.menus"` extension together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct way how to do it is:

```
toolbarManager = new ToolBarManager(SWT.FLAT);                
IServiceLocator workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
IMenuService menuService = (IMenuService) workbench.getService(IMenuService.class);
menuService.populateContributionManager(toolbarManager, TOOLBAR_LOCATION);

toolbar = toolbarManager.createControl(root);
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this code, and it doesn't work because the version of the WorkbenchMenuService that gets returned from the call workbench.getService(IMenuService.class) has a flaw.  The flaw is that the method populateContributionManager(toolbarManager, TOOLBAR_LOCATION) is not implemented and has a //TODO message in it.  This unimplemented method is coming from org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.104.0.v20130204_164612.jar  How did you get your code to work?

Comment: This code works perfectly using Indigo release of Eclipse. But so far does not work for Juno.